# Laravel Eloquest join with max adn min value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

Im trying to build a query that pulls the information from one table and also pulls the max and min value of that product in another table but cannot seem to get this to work.

This is what I have:

```
$rentals = Rentals::select('rentals.main_image','rentals.rental_name','rentals.slug','rentals.summary',DB::raw('max(prices.price) as price_high'),DB::raw('min(prices.price) as price_low'))
->leftjoin('prices', 'rentals.id', '=', 'prices.rental_id')
->where('destination',$destination_id)->paginate(6);
```

This returns 1 row ( there should be 88 ) and it gets me the highest and lowest price in the table regardless of rental_id. There are other factors that will filter into this like dates but for now I just need the rental info plus the highest and lowest price for that rental.

Comment: Add `->groupBy('rentals.id')`.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir that worked. Thanks so much.